# nodejs npm start error with concurrently

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have the following code in package.json:

```
"scripts": {
        "start": "concurrently --kill-others \"npm run _server:run\" \"ng serve --aot --progress=false --proxy-config proxy.conf.json\"",
        "lint:client": "ng lint",
        "lint:server": "tslint './server/**/*.ts' -c ./server/tslint.json --fix",
        "test:client": "ng test",
        "e2e:client": "ng e2e",
        "build": "ng build --prod --sm=false --aot --output-path=dist/client && npm run _server:build",
        "_server:run": "tsc -p ./server && concurrently \"tsc -w -p ./server\" \"nodemon --debug dist/server/bin/www.js\" ",
        "_server:build": "tsc -p ./server",
        "postinstall": "npm run build"
    },
```

if i run:

> npm run _server:run

everything works fine, but if i run:

> npm run start

i get the following error:

```
[0] [1] [0] 'np' n?o ? reconhecido como um comando interno ou externo,
[0] [1] [0] programa operacional ou ficheiro batch.
[0] [1] [2] A sintaxe do nome do ficheiro, do nome do direct?rio ou da etiqueta
do volume ? incorrecta.
[0] [1] [1] 'run' n?o ? reconhecido como um comando interno ou externo,
[0] [1] [1] programa operacional ou ficheiro batch.
[0] [1] [4] 'serve' n?o ? reconhecido como um comando interno ou externo,
[0] [1] [4] programa operacional ou ficheiro batch.
[0] [1] [1] run exited with code 1
[0] [1] --> Sending SIGTERM to other processes..
[0] [1] [2] _server:run" exited with code 1
[0] [1] [0] np exited with code 1
[0] [1] [3] 'n' n?o ? reconhecido como um comando interno ou externo,
[0] [1] [3] programa operacional ou ficheiro batch.
[0] [1] [4] serve exited with code 1
[0] [1] [3] n exited with code 1
```

my windows is in Portuguese so some parts are in Portuguese, but essentially it says np program not recognized .

i'm pretty new to nodejs,i think is something about 'concurrently' but i can't figure out what is the problem

**EDIT**

full package.json:

```
{
    "name": "dynamicflowweb",
    "version": "4.0.9",
    "scripts": {
        "start": "concurrently --kill-others \"npm run _server:run\" \"ng serve --aot --progress=false --proxy-config proxy.conf.json\"",
        "lint:client": "ng lint",
        "lint:server": "tslint './server/**/*.ts' -c ./server/tslint.json --fix",
        "test:client": "ng test",
        "e2e:client": "ng e2e",
        "build": "ng build --prod --sm=false --aot --output-path=dist/client && npm run _server:build",
        "_server:run": "tsc -p ./server && concurrently \"tsc -w -p ./server\" \"nodemon --debug dist/server/bin/www.js\" ",
        "_server:build": "tsc -p ./server",
        "postinstall": "npm run build"
    },
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
        "@agm/core": "^1.0.0-beta.0",
        "@angular/animations": "^4.0.0",
        "@angular/cli": "^1.2.4",
        "@angular/common": "^4.0.0",
        "@angular/compiler": "^4.0.0",
        "@angular/core": "^4.0.0",
        "@angular/forms": "^4.0.0",
        "@angular/http": "^4.0.0",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.0.0",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.0.0",
        "@angular/router": "^4.0.0",
        "angular-bootstrap-md": "*",
        "angular2-jwt": "^0.2.3",
        "chart.js": "2.5.0",
        "classlist.js": "^1.1.20150312",
        "core-js": "^2.4.1",
        "easy-pie-chart": "^2.1.7",
        "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
        "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
        "jsonwebtoken": "^7.4.1",
        "rxjs": "^5.1.0",
        "screenfull": "^3.2.0",
        "web-animations-js": "^2.2.5",
        "webpack": "^2.2.0",
        "zone.js": "^0.8.4"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@angular/cli": "1.0.0",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.0.0",
        "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
        "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
        "codelyzer": "~2.0.0",
        "concurrently": "^3.5.0",
        "jasmine-core": "~2.5.2",
        "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~3.2.0",
        "karma": "~1.4.1",
        "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.0.0",
        "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
        "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^0.2.0",
        "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
        "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
        "nodemon": "^1.11.0",
        "protractor": "~5.1.0",
        "ts-node": "~2.0.0",
        "tslint": "~4.5.0",
        "typescript": "~2.2.0"
    }
}
```

Comment: Use "npm start" . This will execute your start script.

Comment: `npm start` is just a shortcut for `npm run start`, which is the same thing

Comment: Have you installed `concurrently`? What does your `package.json` look like?

Answer (score 4):

The only thing that worked for me is to add **--raw**, so I use

```
concurrently --raw "npm:task1" "npm:task2"
```

I don't know why it works only in this combination. And it is certainly a feature of npm, because other command I tried work perfectly without raw flag. I.e. the following will work fine:

```
concurrently "tsc" "node-sass --output-style compressed index.scss ./out/index.css"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to install concurrently.

The tool is written in Node.js, but you can use it to run any commands.

```
npm install -g concurrently
```

or if you are using it from npm scripts:

```
npm install concurrently --save
```

**Usage**

Remember to surround separate commands with quotes:

```
concurrently "command1 arg" "command2 arg"
```

Otherwise concurrently would try to run 4 separate commands: command1, arg, command2, arg.

In package.json, escape quotes:

```
"start": "concurrently \"command1 arg\" \"command2 arg\""
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/concurrently